# How to find the position of the certain element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the image position inside my div

my Html

```
<div>
  <p>test</p>
  <img src='test1.jpg'/>  
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>  
  <img src='test2.jpg'/>  
  <p>test</p>
  <img src='test2.jpg'/>  --the user clicks this image and I want to know the time it appears. In this case, 2 is what I need.
  <p>test</p>
  <img src='test2.jpg'/>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

I have

```
var imagePosition=0;
$('img').click(function(){
     var imgSource=$(this).attr('src');
    $(this).closest('div').find('img').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('src')==imgSource){
          imagePosition++;
       }
    })
})
```

I can find out how many time the same images appear but I can't tell which image the user clicks and it's position. Are there anyways to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: You mean other than `this.offsetLeft` and `this.offsetTop`?

Comment: So if someone clicks on the div, what is the output you want? The src attribute of the img?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var clickedIndex = $('img[src="'+ $(this).attr('src') +'"]').index(this) + 1;
    console.log(clickedIndex);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6sdC/1/)

Here I built an attribute search of images with the same source attribute as the clicked one, then call [`.index(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) passing the clicked element as reference. As `index` is [0-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), we add 1.

If having the same ancestor `div` is important, just adapt it with `closest` and `find` as was initially:

```
var clickedIndex = 
     $(this).closest('div')
    .find('img[src="'+ $(this).attr('src') +'"]').index(this) + 1;
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6sdC/2/)

---

To get a reference to the clicked image, just use the `this` keyword inside the handler. You can wrap it inside a jQuery object `$(this)` and call jQuery methods on it then.

---

Also, by your question's code comment, I assume that by `position` you actually mean the `index` of the element, but if you'd rather get the literal position of the element you can use the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (relative to document) and [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (relative to parent) methods.

Side-note: If you need to count the number of images with the same source, you can do it in a much easier way with [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
var countImages = $('img[src="'+ $(this).attr('src') +'"]').length;
```

Again, the above assumes to be inside an event handler's scope where `this` references an image element. You can easily adapt it to query for any `src` though.

Comment: What of the second question?

Comment: If by second question you mean getting a reference to the clicked image, simply use `this` inside of the handler.

Comment: I mean getting the position, asked at the end of the last sentence.  I know how to do it myself, just to be clear, but your answer is already here and is pretty thought out save for that one thing.  I thought it would be prudent to suggest it.

Comment: "but I can't tell which image the user clicks and it's position." I think by position the OP actually meant the `index` and not the `offset`/`position`, see the comment on his question's code.

Comment: I see the code comment now, didn't before.  My bad; +1 either way though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index

```
   $('img').click(function(){

         index =  $(this).closest('div').find('img').index(this) + 1;

   });
```